# Finding recurrence relation given the generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

So I'm given the generating function $F(x)={1+2x\over1-3x^2}$
I'm supposed to find the recurrence relation satisfied by fn.
I managed to get it into 2 separate geometric series and derive $f_n = {5(3^n)-(-3^n)\over6}$
but can't derive it in terms of past values of $f_n$.
Help please, I have exam tomorrow!!!

EDIT: I just realised the $f_n$ I derived is wrong, ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

$F(x)=\sum_{i\ge 0}a_ix^i$, where $a_0=1,a_1=2$ and $a_i=3a_{i-2}$ for $i\ge 2$.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating how you arrived at the answer? I have trouble expanding the function.

Comment: @huhehu: I multiplied the left hand of $(1-3x^2)\sum_{i\ge 0}a_ix^i=i+2x$ and equated coefficients.

Comment: Ah yes, I found it! Cheers!

Comment: @huhehu: It’s really just the reverse of the process that you use to derive a generating function from a recurrence.